# Splitting a string and adding the digits inside of the string

Tags: python, string

How would I go about splitting a string up and then adding up the integers inside, with the code below I am able to add up single integers, but if I get a string like "a12b34" I should be able to do 12 + 34 not 1+2+3+4 like the code below does. I am able to do this in C but I do not know how to 100% do it in python.

```
strTest = str(raw_input("Enter an alphanumeric string: "))
total = 0
for ch in strTest:
    if ch.isdigit() == True:
        total = total + int(ch)
print total
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#re.findall) to extract all digits, convert them to integer and then sum the results

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'a12b34'
>>> total = sum(map(int,re.findall(r'-?\d+', s))) # -? is to cover negative values
46
```

This is valid only if you have integers

**EDIT:**

For general cases, where you might have float number as well, consider the following:

```
>>> s = 'a12b32c12.0d11.455'
>>> sum(map(float, re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d+', s)))
67.455
>>> s = 'a12b-32c12.0d-11.455'
>>> sum(map(float, re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d+', s)))
-19.455
```

**EDIT2:**

So what's happening:

1 - `import re` will import and load `re` module, which is a module used to extract complex string format based on the provided pattern. More details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re)

2 - `re.findall` will return all matching string in `s` with the provided pattern `r'-?\d+\d.>\d+'`

3 - The pattern `r'-?\d+\d.>\d+` breakdown (which can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/vN9xB2/11)):

[image]

4 - Now, `re.findall` will return a list of all matches:

```
>>> s = 'a12b-32c12.0d11.455'
>>> re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d+', s)
['12', '-32', '12.0', '11.455']
```

5 - `map` will convert each element from this list from string into float returning a generator:

```
>>> map(float, re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d+', s))
<map object at 0x0000000003873470>
>>> list(map(float, re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d+', s)))
[12.0, -32.0, 12.0, -11.455]
```

6 - Passing the result of `map` to `sum` will sum all elements to their total:

```
>>> sum([12.0, -32.0, 12.0, -11.455])
-19.455
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this does exactly what I want it to do, but I really don't understand what any of it is doing, so do you think you could explain to me what each part is doing? Basically, what is "import re" and everything after the equals sign. Thank you.

Comment: @terrabl...sure I'll update the answer with explanation...meanwhile you can read docs in the referenced link.

Comment: @terrabl ..  check the explanation and let me know if something was not clear

Comment: @terrabl...if you feel that this answer helped you better, then consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do this without using regular expressions?

Comment: @terrabl.,.definitely yes..will update whenever possible..does this mean you cannot use modules?

Comment: Yeah you can use modules.

Comment: For me, I find this regular expression slightly more intuitive, as the floating aspect is contained: `r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?'`.  Like the solution, though.